# Is it safe to use SMBv1 client/server after patching it, on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, security, smb, exploit

As you may know, after numerous ransomware attacks, Microsoft decided to disable SMBv1 by default on Windows OS's.

However despite releasing a patch ([MS17-010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2017/ms17-010)) to address those attacks, it seems that [Microsoft still advocates *not* using it](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858).

Even more confusing is that the patch linked above only seems to address SMBv1 server and not the client:

> This security update resolves vulnerabilities in Microsoft Windows.
> The most severe of the vulnerabilities could allow remote code
> execution if an attacker sends specially crafted messages to a
> Microsoft Server Message Block 1.0 (SMBv1) **server**.

In my case, on my Windows 10 machine, I'd need to use the SMBv1 client to access a network hard drive connected to a modem/router which only support SMBv1 and which is directly connected to the Internet...

Assuming the patch addresses both the SMBv1 server and clients vulnerabilities, why are we still advised to stay away form SMBv1?

Do we really face any serious risks enabling it, after patching it?

Comment: SMBv1 is not considered safe.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm really impressed by the depth of your comment.

Comment: not really. most of the big ransomware these days will attempt to exploit SMBv1 vulnerabilities to gain access to files. I believe NotPetya was one of these.

Comment: @jj_ - There isn’t anything to say.  SMBv1 is not considered safe.  There is a reason it’s disabled by default.  Sometimes less is more

Comment: @Ramhound - yes it's disabled by default *but* MS released a patch for it, so I think it makes sense to ask whether or not it is safe to use, now. If you say it isn't, despite the patch, you should also explain why, which is exactly what I asked in my question. Just saying it isn't, adds nothing to what I already exposed in my question.

Comment: Why take the risk? Upgrade or replace the router. As per your own link **STOP USING SMB1!**

Comment: @FrankThomas - I am asking whether SMBv1 is safe to use *after patching it against known vulnerabilities*... Did you read the full question?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I know I can upgrade or replace my router, but as many of you here I am in the IT field, and when I do something I want to have a solid understanding of the reasons behind it. I am just aiming at knowledge and I don't understand why willing to know a little more than a simple "X is not considered safe" is being payed back with downvotes. Perhaps some people here don't like to admit they don't know that much, and hate realizing they are just following mantras rather than knowledge...

Comment: @jj_ - I didn't downvote, I like your question as a thought experiment but I wouldn't recommend anyone doing it in a real network. In the end, it's all about how many risk you are willing to take and the track record for SMB1 is not great.

Comment: OK, SMBv1 is unsecure with respect to current standards, but in the context of a Home network, who cares? And what if you have a nice and up to date SMBv3 access, but with the password retained in Windows in order to have the remote disk automatically mounted, as most people do? A malware doesn't even has to exploit a vulnerabilty, then, he just has to read to accessible data.

Comment: @PierU I just added a little ldetail that I gave for kind of granted... The router where I was planning to attach the network HDD was actually a *modem-router* connected to the internet... Would you feel safe attaching a storage device there, allowing it to  communicate with the rest of the local network over a compromised protocol? Luckily I didn't... and I never carried on with the project.

Comment: Yes I would feel safe. The fact that this is a modem router doesn’t matter at all, the accessibility to the attached disk  is not different than it would be if the disk was attached to any other machine of the network, and anyway SMB1 won’t compromise the other functionalities of the modem router. What you have to understand is that to exploit any vulnerability of SMB1, a hacker would have FIRST to penetrate your LAN.

Comment: I do understand that a hacker would first have to penetrate the LAN, obviously, and that's exactly why it does matter that the modem/router is connected to the internet... What security could you  expect from a device which came with a non-patched SMB1 service and most importantly which in the following years **did not even release a single firmware upgrade** to fix that, which is what the majority of internet acccess providers will give you by defauilt? That's the perfect type of target for hackers. By not running vulneable services in the LAN I'm at least preventing damage to other devices..

Comment: A SMB share on the LAN is not accessible from the internet, unless you explicitly define a NAT rule for that on the router.

Comment: @PierU ... anyone hacking into the router could easily make themselves appear local to the LAN, so no need to set any NAT rule. And even if that was still required, they could easily set the rule themselves.

Comment: If someone was hacking your router, the security level of SMB1 would definitely be the least of your concerns...

Comment: @PierU someone hacking into my router could end up being stuck there, if the rest of the nextwork is using safe protocols. Or at least it would make it way harder for them to break into other services.

Comment: Hackers who are smart enough to penetrate your router likely won't have much trouble penetrating the rest of your LAN at some point, unless you have a DoD grade LAN. But that's not even the point: even if the router has a full up-to-date SMB3 sharing, someone hacking the router would then easily access the data on an attached disk, without having to exploit any SMB vulnerability.

Comment: In case an external drive is connected to the router and served by the router as a SMB share, then yes, an hacker penetrating the router would be able to access the share no matter which SMB protocol version was in use. However if the SMB share was served by another LAN machine, using an updated SMB protocol would prevent someone penetrating the router from exploiting the SMB share and getting access to it. Therefore I think your initial statement that *"SMB v1 is insecure but in the context of a home network, who cares?"* is still wrong and can be dangerously misleading. Just don't use SMB v1

Comment: OK, but you are somehow moving the goalposts here, as initially you were talking about the SMB server on the router itself. It all depends on what kind of data you have on the share: if it's non-personal multimedia files the security of the share doesn't matter; and I wouldn't put anyway sensitive personal data on an external disk attached to a router, even if it's SMBv3: modem-routers are consumer grade products with very limited sharing capabilities: single user, no management of permissions, no disk encryption, ... what if the disk with your sensitive data is physically stolen for instance?

Comment: ...not to mention also that the firmwares of these modem-routers are generally not regularly patched with security updates, contrary to usual computer OSes. You may have a SMBv3 on the router, but if it has unpatched vulnerabilities at the end it's not really better than having SMBv1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security issue with SMBv1 is a mistake within the protocol design, so even if Microsoft has found a way to block the *particular* attacks found so far, new variations which would evade the block can still be developed.

Trying to keep using SMBv1 would result in a game of Whack-a-mole against the malware writers, requiring everyone to look out for new exploits and create & apply patches for them in a hurry as soon as they appear. As long as SMBv1 would be in wide use, the stream of new exploits would continue.

Microsoft had already announced the deprecation schedule for SMBv1 when the WannaCry worm used the SMBv1 weaknesses to spread like wildfire. So Microsoft decided to solve the problem by accelerating the deprecation schedule: that would eliminate the root cause of the vulnerabilities altogether.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858

> ### SMB1 isn’t safe
>
> When you use SMB1, you lose key protections offered by later SMB protocol versions:
>
> - Pre-authentication Integrity (SMB 3.1.1+). Protects against security downgrade attacks.
> - Secure Dialect Negotiation (SMB 3.0, 3.02). Protects against security downgrade attacks.
> - Encryption (SMB 3.0+). Prevents inspection of data on the wire, MiTM attacks. In SMB 3.1.1 encryption performance is even better than signing!
> - Insecure guest auth blocking (SMB 3.0+ on Windows 10+) . Protects against MiTM attacks.
> - Better message signing (SMB 2.02+). HMAC SHA-256 replaces MD5 as the hashing algorithm in SMB 2.02, SMB 2.1 and AES-CMAC replaces that in SMB 3.0+. Signing performance increases in SMB2 and 3.
>
> The nasty bit is that no matter how you secure all these things, if your clients use SMB1, then a man-in-the-middle can tell your client to *ignore all the above* . All they need to do is block SMB2+ on themselves and answer to your server’s name or IP. Your client will happily derp away on SMB1 and share all its darkest secrets unless you required encryption on that share to prevent SMB1 in the first place. This is not theoretical – we’ve seen it.

That quote is written by Ned Pyle, the owner of the SMB protocol at Microsoft at the time of writing. So that's as straight from the horse's mouth as you can get.

Comment: Ok I understand than newer protocol versions are stronger, but do you have any sources clearly stating that *despite the patch* SMBv1 is still vulnerable to new variations of those attacks, more than how new versions of the protocol would be? Because in my research I could not find this. Basically *I want to believe you* (and others too); I'm only searching for confirmations of what you said, but I couldn't find any. Could you find me one single webpage clearly stating that *patched* SMBv1 is still more vulnerable than, say SMBv2? Shouldn't be hard to find, if this is such a simple question...

Comment: Hi @Redoman, perhaps this article would help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/smbv1-not-installed-by-default-in-windows

Comment: @telcoM thank you! That was the level of detail I was looking for :) I can finally consider this quesion closed and correctly answered! Good job!